# Tint UIImage in Cell - ObjectiveC

Tags: objective-c

I have been trying to tint a UIImage in the code snippet below but cannot work it out. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
    aUiCell.objChatOnCell = objChatOnCell;

    UIImage *bgImage;
    bgImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_chat_me"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 20, 30, 20)];

    UIImageView *bgImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[bgImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate]];
    bgImageView.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];

    aUiCell.imgSenderBack.image = bgImageView.image;
    aUiCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    aUiCell.lblChatDateTime.text = [UtilitySwift dateTimeStamp:objChatOnCell.newtimestamp.description];
    aUiCell.lblChatDateTime.textColor = [Colors hexStringToUIColor:[Colors getuserChatTextColor] alpha:1.0];

    [aUiCell LoadCell];
    aUiCell.txtViewSenderChat.textColor = [Colors hexStringToUIColor:[Colors getuserChatTextColor] alpha:1.0];
    return aUiCell;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing in your code is setting the `tintColor` of the imageView instead of the image itself.

In changing the color/tintColor/maskColor of a `UIImage`, you will to manipulate its context as far as I know. So you can use this `UIImage` Category if you want.

**UIImage+YourProject.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (YourProject)
- (UIImage *)maskWithColor:(UIColor *)maskColor;
@end
```

**UIImage+YourProject.m**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@implementation UIImage (YourProject)

- (UIImage *)maskWithColor:(UIColor *)maskColor
{
    NSParameterAssert(maskColor != nil);

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.size.width, self.size.height);
    UIImage *newImage = nil;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRect.size, NO, self.scale);
    {
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0f, -(imageRect.size.height));

        CGContextClipToMask(context, imageRect, self.CGImage);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, maskColor.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(context, imageRect);

        newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}

@end
```

and call that method like so:

```
UIColor *red = [UIColor redColor];
UIImage *icon = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"home"] maskWithColor:red];
[self.imageView setImage:icon];
```

Hope it helps!